# JS. Сортировка по количеству вхождения символов

Tags: javascript, сортировка

Нужно рассчитать частоту вхождений каждого символа текста в единицах и в процентах от общего числа символов. Вывод скрипта необходимо отсортировать по частоте вхождения символов от самого частого к наименее часто встречающемуся в текста.

```
var str = "K;;KKLSLJOIWOIOIWUIYUERYUOOKJ,M,MCX,MXCMX,MXC,M)";
var counts = {};
var ch, index, len, count, sum;
var arr = {}
for (index = 0, len = str.length; index < len; ++index)
{
    ch = str.charAt(index); // JavaScript метод charAt() возвращает символ по заданному индексу внутри строки.
    count = counts[ch];
    counts[ch] = count ? count + 1 : 1; // Условный оператор. Если этот символ уже встречался в этой строчке, то прибавляем единицу, если нет, то возвращем значение 1

}
for (ch in counts)
{
   console.log(ch + " частота: " + counts[ch] + " в процентах: " + (counts[ch]/len)*100) + "%";
}

console.log("Всего символов: " + len);
```

Вот со сортировкой у меня проблемы. Буду очень благодарна за помощь.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069666/sorting-object-property-by-values

Answer (score 3):

Лучше воспользоваться итерацией по строке (цикл `for...of`): так и проще, и обеспечивается гарантия, что символы Юникода из суррогатных пар будут правильно обработаны (в вашем варианте стоит добавить в строку замысловатый иероглиф или эмодзи — и скрипт на них споткнётся):

```js
const str = 'K;;KKLSLJOIWOIOIWUIYUERYUOOKJ,M,MCX,MXCMX,MXC,M)';

let length = 0;
const simpleStatistics = {};

for (const symbol of str) {
  length++;
  simpleStatistics[symbol] ??= 0;
  simpleStatistics[symbol]++;
}

const statisticsWithPercents = Object.entries(simpleStatistics).map(
  ([symbol, count]) => ({ symbol, count, percent: count / length * 100 })
);

statisticsWithPercents.sort((a, b) => b.count - a.count);

console.log(`Всего символов: ${length}`);
console.log(statisticsWithPercents);
```

Comment: Еще спред-оператор корректно разбивает строки с многобайтовыми символами, насколько я помню (т.е. когда нужен индекс, можно попробовать через временный массив и `forEach`... хотя это сильнее пожрет ресурсы чем `for..of`).

Answer (score 0):

Код на скорую руку, однако работает.

```js
var str = "K;;KKLSLJOIWOIOIWUIYUERYUOOKJ,M,MCX,MXCMX,MXC,M)",
counts = {},
ch, index, len, count, sum,
arr = [],
result = [];
for (index = 0, len = str.length; index < len; ++index) {
    ch = str.charAt(index); // JavaScript метод charAt() возвращает символ по заданному индексу внутри строки.
    count = counts[ch];
    counts[ch] = count ? count + 1 : 1; // Условный оператор. Если этот символ уже встречался в этой строчке, то прибавляем единицу, если нет, то возвращем значение 1
}

for (ch in counts) {
  arr.push([ch, counts[ch]]);
  
  console.log(ch + " частота: " + counts[ch] + " в процентах: " + (counts[ch]/len)*100) + "%";
}

arr.sort(function(a, b) {
    return b[1] - a[1];
});

for(let elem of arr) {
  for (let i = 0; i < elem[1]; i++){
    result.push(elem[0]);
  }
}

console.log("Всего символов: " + len);
console.log(result);
```